# IPhone HTML5 Feature Support

Tags: iphone, html

Does anyone have a link to a definitive list of HTML5 features various browsers / platforms support?  In particular I need to know which features of HTML5 the IPhone supports.  Not having an IPhone myself http://html5test.com is not much use to me.

Comment: Of course if someone has an iphone to hand it would be great if they could visit the page and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full output from html5test.com on an iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.1 in the HTML pane here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHQYC/).

Comment: Thanks for that Liza. The "Related specifications" section seems to be missing (includes the storage section which is quite important for me)

Comment: Oops, sorry. Here's an updated version with the Related specifications bit at the end (just as text, the HTML pasting isn't working): http://jsfiddle.net/FHQYC/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best I can come up with as an answer so far is that the following are supported:

- canvas
- local databases
- video

### References:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Desktop/DataManagement/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008253

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/GraphicsMediaAndVisualEffects/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008269

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone/iPad I'd check http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action

Comment: Yes, I've been there hence the links in my answer but there's not much information there.  It would be nice if they supplied a definitive HTML5 support list on there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/ shoul be your resource.