# make video show on iphone/ipad html

Tags: html

Is there a solution so when I visit my site using IPhone or IPad it will display the video or I could be able to watch it? or Flash is not yet supported on Iphone/Ipad?
Please help.. many thanks

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML 5 than there is a tag named VIDEO for displaying video.

here is link of W3C : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html

**Note : if you are not using than just skip it**

Answer (score 0):

As its common knowledge Flash will most likely never be supported on those devices.

You can use HTML5 it will work on iPad and iPhone 4.
Ref : [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512118/iphone-html5-feature-support) &  [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041819/non-flash-no-plugin-video-chat)  are seeking something similar.

As far as browser support for HTML5 video is concerned you can view the table here :
[HTML5 Video Reference, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Table)

You could also have a browser sniffer that displays appropriate content depending on the device (HTML5 for iPhone/iPad  & flash for the rest of them).